# Override built-in method in Typescript and delete the old method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know I can use declaration merging to add a new definition to built-in methods like this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  keys<T>(o: T & (T extends any[] ? never : object): string[];
}
```

I want this definition of `Object.keys` to disallow arrays. However, this adds a new overloaded definition to `Object.keys`, it doesn't remove the existing definitions. If I call `Object.keys({})`, it uses my new definition. If I call `Object.keys([])`, it skips my definition and uses the built-in definition.

Is there a way to delete the old definitions of `Object.keys`?

**Edit:** for this particular problem, I realized I could just do `keys(o: any[]): never`. However, it'll be useful to know a general solution.

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible to enforce an error calling `Object.keys([])`